# Specific link not loading in WebView on some droids

Tags: android, ssl, webview, loading

I have an app out which displays this link in a web view when a user presses e-mail:

https://marauder.millersville.edu/mail/index.pl

I developed the app on an Droid X, and on my phone the link loads fine, but I have had reports from users who have an Incredible & Droid X that the link loads a blank screen.

I have tested it myself on a friends Incredible, and it indeed only loads a white screen, but I have have tested it on various other android devices and its loads fine.

And every other links also loads fine on the Incredible. I am assuming it has something to do with the SSL, being a https. I had troubles with this link on an iPhone but was able to fix it. What puzzles me is why it works fine on some devices and not on others..

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Here is how I am setting up my web view:

```
    // setup webview
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setWebChromeClient(new InternalWebViewClient());

    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    web.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Does this link load normally in browser on Incredible?

Comment: @Peter Knego I'll have to try that when I get a chance. But my friend who also has a Droid X just showed me its not working on their device either; but like I said its working fine on my Droid X :?

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of is that this devices have different trusted root certificates installed and this site uses SSL certificate from CA that is not present on those devices. Loadin page in browser should check this.

Comment: @Peter Knego Just tested on my friends Droid X and the link works in the regular browser, but it does ask to view and accept the certificate.. Should I be doing something in my code to allow this? I'll post what I am setting in my WebView in a minute

Comment: They are probably using a self- signed certificate. There are ways around it with WebView, mostly via not performing the certificate check. http://r3gis.fr/blog/index.php?post/2009/11/17/Android-WebView-and-ssl-self-signed-certificates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl

Comment: @Peter Knego I ended up fixing my issue (I believe) using the 2nd link you posted. If you post that as an answer I will accept it! THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are trying to load uses self signed certificates. The solution is to ignore certificate checking as described here: [Does the Web View on Android support SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl)