# getting Error "403 forbidden access is denied" android

Tags: android

Iam trying to open one website url on the webview.But iam getting Error "403 forbidden access is denied".How fix this issue? Iam using the wifi connection and i also written internet permission in the manifest file. Like this

How to solve this issue?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you open that url in a browser?

Comment: Paste the `AndroidManifest` here, as well as the code you use to open the page (Only that part).

Comment: This answer gives a good hint about ssl and webviews:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5978391/891479

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Adding this code on your Web Client:

```
 public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                handler.proceed();
            }
```

It will allow webview to load the page , in case of SSL error with website

Comment: It is working now, but webview  asking like Complete action using Browser, Opera Mini?

Comment: How to open the url directly?

Comment: How to open the url on the default browser?

Comment: You should set webview client for your webview.

Comment: To open url in default browser, opem google chrome or opera mini browser  and paste the url, it shall open it.

Comment: This answer need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue in 2018. Try the below code and read my explanation.

There are few possible reasons about why you can get the 403 Forbidden error. I have identified 2 of them.

1. It is an SSL issue.
2. Your `User Agent` is blocked by the website.

Here is how you set the SSL configurations. Here the `newsWebView` is a `WebView`.

```
newsWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                }

                public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
```

This is how you set the `User Agent`. I am setting the Google Chrome agent, the one we normally find in our phones.

```
newsWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev>");
```