# Android webview return 403 error unauthorized

Tags: android

I have a problem when I load a webview in Android

this is my code, is very basic

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);
```

and this is the URL

http://comercios.transferbeet.com:14616/TransferAppsWsUat/register/welcomeWallet

As can you see, I can access without problems from chrome or any browser, but in my Android webview returns

HTTP 403 - Forbidden

I have two environments

with the second

http://comercios.transferbeet.com:14616/TransferAppsWsMtto/register/welcomeWallet

the webview loads without problems.

But the most strange is that in another app project, the first webview loads fine

I can't find the problem :( I'm desperate.

Thanks for your help

The ssl isn't the problem. Webview loads fine un another app and never pass through onReceivedSslError only by onreceivedErrorHttp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787629/getting-error-403-forbidden-access-is-denied-android

Comment: The ssl isn't the problem. I put onreceivedsslerror, and never pass through that exception only for onreceivedErrorHttp.

Answer (score 1):

How to Fix Error 403: 1. Clear Proxy - Go to Settings -> Wireless and Networks -> Mobile Network then APN (Access Point Name) -> then Select Clear Proxy Option - After all these steps you can re-try downloading your material.

Comment: I did it, 

public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());

Comment: may be you should return false in UrlLoading() method.

Comment: now you can try with another site url if that work fine then problem in this URl .

Comment: But I tried the same URL in another app and works fine, it's very very weird.

Comment: you have same implemented here like another app?

Comment: Yes, I put in another app a webview inside an activity and loads correctly the same URL

Comment: have you added permission in manifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ?

Comment: Yes of course, as I said before in my post, http://comercios.transferbeet.com:14616/TransferAppsWsMtto/register/welcomeWallet works fine but env Uat, not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I think the problem is different. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
setDomStorageEnabled(true).
```

I have fixed by this.