# Webview doesn't load the URL , but browser does

Tags: android, webview

So from my first screen I am passing a URL to an activity to launch in webview. But when webview is launched , it shows "`web page not available - The web page at URL might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address`"

But when i launch the same URL in android browser, it works fine.  Here is my code for launching that URL in webview

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = "";
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("loginURL");
    WebView urlWebView = new WebView(this);
    urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    urlWebView.loadUrl(url);
    this.setContentView(urlWebView);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add internet permission in manifest file? `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Yes, I have added internet permission

Comment: You sure ur getting correct URL in `url` string?

Comment: Check your URL start with`http://` or `https://`

Comment: Yes, it starts with https://

Comment: Debugg the code copy rhe url and paste it on the browser and check.

Comment: It works in browser, even my computer browser.

Comment: How to handle certificates issue if the URL I am trying to connect has self-signed SSL certificate?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was that the URL I was using has `https://` and SSL certificate for the URL was self-signed. The solution from [Does the Web View on Android support SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl) helped me fixed the issue.

I added below part in my code

```
import android.net.http.*; //added this import statement

urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
```

Hope this will help other users.

Comment: Beware. Applications or updates using this approach will be rejected in Google Play. See [this post](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387).

Comment: @kibitzerCZ - Yup, I am aware of that. Google asks for showing a warning message for using self-signed SSL certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the url string you're loading has "www" prefixed to it, i.e. "https://www.google.com" and not "https://google.com"

Weirdly enough, this fixed the issue, at least on my end.

Comment: This worked for me too, specifically with this exact URL. Wonder why.