# WebView images are not showing with HTTPS

Tags: android, android-webview

My application opens a web view to show HTML page, which is hosted with HTTPS contains one image(image coming from http). On some devices image is not showing but for all other devices its working fine.
I checked with multiple devices like Nexus, Samsung s6/s4, Moto G2 and others. Only on Samsung S4/S6, nexus image is not showing. but for all other devices its working fine. Even i tried with WI-FI, data carrier, and multiple OS versions but no luck.

Please help to solve this.

some observations:-

1) On each device i am getting same warning :- 
[blocked] The page at '***page url***' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from '***image source***': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

2) same page if i am opening in web browser, working fine on all devices.

My Code

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.m_web_view);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mainUrl = bean.getUrl();
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
    mWebView.loadUrl(mainUrl);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());



    private class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    //some code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
            SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }


}
```

Comment: may be it is a problem of self signed certificate, can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Mixed content using HTTP and HTTPS on WebViews are disabled by default starting Lollipop. Is possible that is not working on devices with Lollipop?
If this is the case, you can change the default WebView setting on Lollipop using:

```
webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

Documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMixedContentMode(int)

Comment: Thanks you are the savior :)

Comment: @AjitSharma For anyone coming here from Google, a better option might be to use `WebSettings .MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` since that will allow images, videos, and other content that is less likely to be used to attack a user.

Comment: Works Like Charm. Saved my day. Thank you @Pollizzio

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes, saved me a ton of time!

Comment: If I am calling the `webview` from a class via a JAR file and don't have access to the `webview` object, how can I enforce this setting?

Answer (score 3):

Use the follwoing code. You can open https using the following code,
 extend the `onReveivedSslError` method of `WebViewClient` and proceed if any error occurred
Here is an example

```
    WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
     handler.proceed() ;
     }

}
```

Comment: Not working.  I am adding my code in comment. Please look and let me know if anything i missed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a SSL property of webview so to handle this you will have to use following code.

```
engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
 handler.proceed() ;
 }
}
```

And in handler you can run webview image url easily.

Comment: Do not implement this onReceivedSslError Google play will reject your app