# WebView does not load some images

Tags: android, image, webview

I have the following configuration of WebView and not charging some images in Lollipop version 5.0 and higher. Lower loads normally (tested in the 4.0, 4.1 and 2.3).
By checking any error logs is displayed.

```
if(!url.equals("")) {

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvProduct);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(LoadingDialog.instanceProgressDialog().isShowing()) {
                LoadingDialog.dismissDialog();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            if(LoadingDialog.instanceProgressDialog().isShowing()) {
                LoadingDialog.dismissDialog();
            }
            Log.e(ConstantsAdAlive.ERROR, "****Error: " + description + " code: " + errorCode);
        }
    });

} else {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.INIT_ERROR)
        .setMessage(R.string.webview_error)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(
            android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    WebViewActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })
        .create()
        .show();
}

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
} else {
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));
}

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 15) {
    // android 4.1.2 - sony, resfresh WebView
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found an answer which solved my problem: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509277/webview-images-are-not-showing-with-https)