# Android Webview use self-signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate

```
public class NewSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");  
    private KeyStore setCert(){
        String skuCertBin ="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"+
                                             "SOMETHING TEXT HERE"+
                                      "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";  
        KeyStore trustStore=null;  
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream derInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(skuCertBin.getBytes());  
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");  
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(derInputStream);  
            String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();  
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());  
            trustStore.load(null, null);  
            trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        return trustStore;  
    }
    public NewSSLSocketFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        super();  
        KeyStore trustStore = setCert();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");  
        tmf.init(trustStore);  
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    }
....................
}
```

My SSL Socket code

When I use Jsoup parse, I applying on above code

But When using WebView, View don't showing web pages only **"https://"**

```
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullWebView);  
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);  
                return true;  
            }
        });  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  

        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I found setCertificate method but "This method was deprecated in API level 17. Calling this function has no useful effect, and will be ignored in future releases."

How can I use these custom cert on webview

---

```
final PrivateKey privateKey = newSSLSocketFactory.getPrivateKey();
final X509Certificate[] cert= new X509Certificate[1];
cert[0] = newSSLSocketFactory.getCert();

@Override
public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, ClientCertRequest request) {
    Log.d("WebviewCheck","cert Working");
    request.proceed(privateKey, cert);
 }
```

I use these code on each onCreate and new WebViewClient
But Android don't call onReceivedClientCertRequest, not showing "WebviewCheck" Log

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private int section_number_fragment = 0;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        private void setFragmentNumber(int n) {
            this.section_number_fragment = n;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            fragment.setFragmentNumber(sectionNumber);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int fragmentFile;
            switch (section_number_fragment) {
                case 1:
                    fragmentFile = R.layout.fragment_left;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragmentFile = R.layout.fragment_center;
                    break;
                default:
                    // section_number_fragment == 3
                    fragmentFile = R.layout.fragment_right;
                    break;
            }

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(fragmentFile, container, false);
            if ( section_number_fragment==1) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                if (loginCookies == null) {
                    transaction.replace(R.id.leftFragment, new LogoutFragment());
                }
                else
                    transaction.replace(R.id.leftFragment, new LoginFragment());
                transaction.commit();
            }

            if (section_number_fragment != 1 && section_number_fragment != 2) {
                webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.renewWebView);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, ClientCertRequest request) {
                        Log.d("WebviewCheck","cert Working");
                        request.proceed(privateKey, cert);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
                        if ( url.equals(ManageUrl.circulationPageUrl))
                            webViewFinishChk=false;
                    }
                   @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                       super.onPageFinished(view,url);
                       if ( url.equals(ManageUrl.circulationPageUrl))
                           webViewFinishChk=true;
                   }
                });
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                                .setTitle("AppTitle")
                                .setMessage(message)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                result.confirm();
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .create()
                                .show();

                        return true;
                    }
                    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                                .setTitle("AppTitle")
                                .setMessage(message)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                            {
                                                result.confirm();
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                        {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                            {
                                                result.cancel();
                                            }
                                        })
                                .create()
                                .show();

                        return true;
                    }
                });
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

                ListView borrowListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.borrowBookList);
                borrowListView.setAdapter(borrowAdapter);
                /*
                Button refresh = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.refreshBorrowBook);
                refresh.performClick();
                */
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

newSSLSocketFactory, privateKey and cert is MainActiviy's private static variable, Init on onCreate method

Why viewpager's webview still not showing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15590041/1576416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String sslCertificate = error.getCertificate().toString();
String mySslCertificate = new SslCertificate(cert).toString();
if ( sslCertificate.equals(mySslCertificate) )
    handler.proceed();
```

These codes add on WebView `onReceivedSslError` methods

I think It's not a perfect solution. But These codes check some of SSL Cert

Not showing popup message(dialog)

Comment: Just as further reference for anyone attempting something like this, if you add a suitable `onReceivedSslError` implemention but _still_ get failed/dropped/rejected connections, ensure that you're not generating a new self-signed certificate for each connection/request.  Calling `handler.proceed()` whitelists _only_ the specific certificate involved in the current request, and after the `proceed()` call is made Android abandons the current request and begins a new one from scratch.  If the new request uses a different certificate from the original, then it will still be blocked.